# Simple program to display 3D mesh?

Tags: linux, visualization, mesh

for a university project I have to compute a 3D mesh, then display it.
By mesh I mean a list of triangles, where each point has a specific elevation.
What is the easiest tool that exists both on windows and linux that would allow me to display such a mesh?
I just want to be able to visualize the mesh and rotate it, and I can code any specific mesh format needed to be used as an input.
What I mostly want is a tool that is easy to install for the final user of my program.

Answer (score 2):

Almost every tool reads the *.obj format, for example MeshMan, MeshLab and ArtOfIllusion. They all work under Windows and Linux. Geomview (*.off-Files) is also great, but hard to install under Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using for this purpose `osgviewer` from [OpenSceneGraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't know about the *easiest* tool, but have you tried [Blender](http://www.blender.org/)? It's cross platform.

Comment: I'm more looking for something much more lightweight

Answer (score 0):

There are some standard file formats for triangle meshes.  Try outputing to .ply file and using one of the existing viewers for that.

I tend to use VTK file formats since I work in scientific visualization;  that would be overkill  for you.

In fact, I wrote a VTK/QT based app for viewing meshes that can handle .ply files https://github.com/HalCanary/vtkviewer.